# Why is an instruction being sometimes executed twice when using threads C

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have the following code which basically creates two threads, one reads a character, and the other one types it untill the letter f is passed :

```
char c;
int att = 1;

void* th_read(void *k){     
    
    do {    
        while(!att);
        printf("type a character : ");
        scanf(" %c",&c);
        att = 0;
        
    }while(c != 'f');
    
    
    exit(0);
}

void* th_write(void *k){    
    
    
    do {    
        while(att);
        printf("character typed is : %c \n",c);
        att = 1;
        
    }while(c != 'f');
    
    
    exit(0);
}

void main(){
    int i;
    pthread_t pth_id[2];
    
    
    pthread_create(&pth_id[0], 0,th_read,NULL);
    printf("Main: reading thread created with id = %ld\n", pth_id[0]);
    
    pthread_create(&pth_id[1], 0,th_write,NULL);
    printf("Main: writing thread created with id= %ld\n",pth_id[1]);
    
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) pthread_join(pth_id[i],NULL);
    
    exit(0);
}
```

my problem is that the instruction `printf("character typed is : %c \n",c);` is sometimes executed twice when the user types 'f'.

example :

[image]

Comment: Why `exit(0)` at the end of thread function? `exit()` terminates entire process. Just return from thread function to terminate thread.

Comment: @dimich yes my bad was treating it like a fork process, but how does that relate to the instruction being executed twice?

Comment: You need a mutex and some condition variables to synchronize your threads.

Comment: At least one of your threads uses the value of `c` while it is uninitialised. There are probably many other problems - sharing variables between threads like this with no mutex or semaphore or similar will not work.

Comment: `while(att);` won't work too well. Either do: `volatile int att = 1;` or much better: use `stdatomic.h` primitives: `while (atomic_load(&att));` and set it with `atomic_store(&att, some_value);`

Comment: ... or declare it as `_Atomic int att`, supposing your implementation supports that. (`_Atomic` is a standard feature of C11 and later, but a conditional one -- implementations are not required to support it.)

Comment: Multi-threading with shared variables and without proper synchronization may fail in all kind of strange ways. You may be able to find an explanation for a specific behavior on your specific system but the C code can't be used for investigating what's going on. You'll have to look at the generated machine code and you need expert knowledge of several system things. For instance the processor and it's pipeline, cache system, etc.. All that isn't worth your time... Instead spend your time on learning how to write proper multi-thread code.

Comment: Try to replace scanf with fgets and use the first character of array.

Comment: @RafikBouloudene I would rather ask "Why sometimes it seems to work as expected?". Among other things `exit()` flushes stdio streams. `exit()` is not thread-safe, so anything can happen. BTW, `void main()` is not a valid `main` signature in C.

Comment: @RafikBouloudene Regarding this particular behavior, i would speculate on following scenario: `exit()` from one thread triggers stdout to flush and writes buffer content to stdout descriptor. Buffer is not cleared yet. At the same time `exit()` from second thread also triggers stdout to flush, it writes the same buffer content to stdout descriptor once again. Typical race condition.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a race condition due to unprotected, non-atomic use of shared (global) variables.

I suggest you go through the whole https://deadlockempire.github.io/ series, it is a very good starting point to get into the multi-threading concepts.